# If-else statements won't work

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am trying to make a communication between two simultaneously running threads
through a global variable.

```
char dir='w'; //global var


UINT EditDir ( LPVOID pParam);//accepts dir from user in a loop
UINT Move ( LPVOID pParam);   //processes dir (its incomplete)

int main()
{
    ........
    ........
    CWinThread* pThread1 = AfxBeginThread(EditDir,(LPVOID)NULL);
    CWinThread* pThread2 = AfxBeginThread(Move,(LPVOID)NULL);
    WaitForSingleObject(pThread1, INFINITE);
    ........
    ........
}

UINT EditDir(LPVOID pParam)
{
    bool end=false; 
    while (!end)
    {
        ::dir = getchar();
        Sleep(10);
        if (::dir=='q')end=true;//***************************************
    }
return 0;
}

UINT Move ( LPVOID pParam)
{
    //process dir in a loop
    return 0;
}
```

The `if` statement in `while` loop doesn't work its like the compiler removes the line before compilation.

after I press `q` the loop should end but it keeps on going.

Where am I wrong ?

Comment: @EdHeal please explain why and where ?...

Comment: Try compiling with "-O0" flag to check if compiler optimization is actually the reason

Comment: Please explain how the communication is occurring between the thread and where is the other thread created.

Comment: @EdHeal edited.....also I just started working on the function EditDir(...) that's why the second function is empty

Comment: Communication between thread with a variable, it sounds like [mutex](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/mutex/mutex/) for me. So maybe you need an [atomic](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/atomic/) variable.

Comment: At this moment in time - there is no communication between the threads - as one thread does nothing.

Comment: Have you tried some std::cout to see where the thread go? Or gdb if you prefer.

Comment: @EdHeal please feel free edit my question as you like but please I want to know why my if-statement is not working.

Comment: Why do you believe that it is not working?

Comment: @MathieuVanNevel I added one after the if statement and it prints whatever I type. and the loop doesn't break after I press 'q'

Comment: You need to post the real code that reproduces the error. We can't see what's wrong in your real code by looking at some different code you happen to have posted.

Comment: Have you tried the return key as the terminal may be buffered. Also `getchar` returns an `int` - please read the manual

Comment: @EdHeal wow....after hitting two or three times....the program exits...

Comment: So you print ::dir, and there was the decimal value of 'q' in it? Sorry i can't try compile your code I'm on linux. Try c++11 thread next time.

Comment: One would have done - the `sleep(10)`  slows things down

Comment: Yes sleep 10 sec make it hard to hit the key when you want to.

Comment: @MathieuVanNevel thats 10 ms not second.....and its there to make the loop stable....and make less burden....I have seen some places where the Sleep(...) saves  your loop from crashing.

Comment: @EdHeal I answered my question please check it out....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the mistake........

```
CWinThread* pThread2 = AfxBeginThread(Move,(LPVOID)NULL);//  #1
WaitForSingleObject(pThread1, INFINITE);  //                 #2
```

`pThread` is an object of a class....... not a  handle and

```
WaitForSingleObject(HANDLE hHandle,DWORD dwMilliSeconds)// needs a handle
```

so what we do in between line #1 and #2 is

```
HANDLE hThread;
hThread=pThread->m_hThread;
```

and pass `hThread` in WaitForSingleObject(...) and not pThread.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of things can go wrong with that code.

- Compiler might optimize it so that dir is stored in a register and not reflected to the other function.
- Compiler or processor might reorder statements which would result in some strange behaviour.
- Write aliasing (your code write to some other variable that happens to be next to dir, and the processor optimizes the write to work with a block, effectively overwriting dir).
- Out of thin air results.
- Hitting low level(L1) caches that hold different values.

and much more.

You need to use thread-safe constructs. Use at least std::atomic to prevent write aliasing and a couple of other compiler optimizations that are not thread-safe.
You can also add a mutex to protect access to the variable.

Probably the best set-up is if one thread reads the char from input and pushes a copy into a producer-consumer queue or communication channel that you get from a well tested and well maintained library.

Comment: Has nothing to do with the question at hand.